# Scala : Define implicit functions in an object or in a class

Tags: scala, concurrency, playframework-2.0, instance, implicit

I am learning Play2 framework and start using implicit functions. I am converting some `Position` object to Json :

```
implicit val locationWrites = new Writes[Position] {
    def writes(position: Position) = Json.obj(
      "lat" -> position.lat,
      "lon" -> position.lon
    )
}
```

Should I do :

```
object JsonConversion {
  implicit val locationWrites = new Writes[Position] {
    def writes(position: Position) = Json.obj(
      "lat" -> position.lat,
      "lon" -> position.lon
    )
  }
}
```

or should I do :

```
class JsonConversion {
  implicit val locationWrites = new Writes[Position] {
    def writes(position: Position) = Json.obj(
      "lat" -> position.lat,
      "lon" -> position.lon
    )
  }
}
```

And then import this `class` or `object` where these implicit functions will be used.

What is the underlying difference in terms of instances and scalability of such implicit functions, for instance if they are to be called in a concurrent manner ?

Comment: How are you going to "import a class"? Try it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither really. There is a much cleaner way to keep all your domain together and something people usually tend to forget. **You can put implict in the companion object**

Here's where you should really put them:

```
class Position { ... }
object Position {
  implicit val positionWrites = new Writes[Position] {
    def writes(position: Position) = Json.obj(
    "lat" -> position.lat,
    "lon" -> position.lon
    )
  }
}
```

By default, implicit resolution will look into the companion object. This prevents the domain from being scattered and there will be no weird files full of JSON formats. You can keep things coupled in the right places and it's easy to know where stuff needs to change if you update your classes.

On a side note, Play has more advanced JSON format generation using some fun macros. You can use `Json.format[Type]` or `Json.writes[Type]` or just `Json.reads[Type]` to simply generate the format you need with no manual effort.

```
implicit val positionFormat = Json.format[Position]
```

Comment: coupling domain models with json staffs is one the things that you should avoid of it.

Formatters are mostly used in api/service/web modules. however the domain model itself coming from business problem and has nothing todo with how you want to represent them to the client.

I am sure nobody like to change the domain models to add new formatters  for instance for ProtoBuf, Avro, XML, ...

Comment: Hi @SorooshSarabadani You've got a simple Play app for someone who just started. Most people have kilometric traits they mix in to everything, that's a way to go, but for the simple scenario why are you over-complicating it?

Comment: Hi Flavian, I am just explaining why experienced developers tend to forget such simple thing ;)

Comment: @SorooshSarabadani don't worry I know your angle and I agree. But the above pattern makes life slightly easier, as you don't need to remember to import things and you can avoid any kind of auto-magical implicit errors that are hard to debug. If you're not building protobuf based micro services which most of the time you're not, this is clean cut and easy.

Comment: Even if you are not building protobuf based micro services, I am sure you don't really like to have dependency to play-json in your domain module

Comment: Thanks Flavian any comment on performance/concurrency Of methods calling from a singleton ?

Comment: HI @Antonin, 0 really, it's just a static field being accessed that's all. The implicit resolution is compile time only, so no performance penalty whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your implicit method in an object and import it in this way:

```
import JsonConversion._
```

From performance point of view you should not have any concerns, since many calls could be executed with no side effect.

Comment: Tank you Soroosh Sarabadani, I was thinking about having an instance (an instanciated class: objectif but not singleton) in the scope of each function converting Position to Json ? The fact that there is no side effect means that the function can be called from a singleton on a concurrent manner ?

Comment: You don't really need to do that and don't worry about the scalability. 
Since your class has no state, instantiating it several times has no outcome for you.

Referential transparency is a good reason to call a method in concurrent manner with no problem. 
Bilions of concurrent calls of these kinds of functions can be executed without making any kind of bottlenecks or problems.